# ImageView onTouchListener: cant touch the imageview behind

Tags: java, android, imageview, touch-event, ontouchlistener

I got a tutorial of imageview transformation, w/c I really need. [here is the link](http://judepereira.com/blog/multi-touch-in-android-translate-scale-and-rotate/). It works fine but I need to have some modification. My problem here is, when I add the second imageview, I cant modify the first imageview that I added. It seems that I can't touch it because it is behind the 2nd view. I've read a comment in the link, that is asking for this problem too and he resolve it by doing settag and gettag. I've no idea how to do it. Any suggestion guys? thanks.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnTouchListener {

    // these matrices will be used to move and zoom image
    private Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
    private Matrix savedMatrix = new Matrix();
    // we can be in one of these 3 states
    private static final int NONE = 0;
    private static final int DRAG = 1;
    private static final int ZOOM = 2;
    private int mode = NONE;
    // remember some things for zooming
    private PointF start = new PointF();
    private PointF mid = new PointF();
    private float oldDist = 1f;
    private float d = 0f;
    private float newRot = 0f;
    private float[] lastEvent = null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        ImageView view = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        ImageView view2 = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
        view.setOnTouchListener(this);
        view2.setOnTouchListener(this);
    }

    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        // handle touch events here
        ImageView view = (ImageView) v;
        switch (event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                start.set(event.getX(), event.getY());
                mode = DRAG;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
                oldDist = spacing(event);
                if (oldDist > 10f) {
                    savedMatrix.set(matrix);
                    midPoint(mid, event);
                    mode = ZOOM;
                }
                lastEvent = new float[4];
                lastEvent[0] = event.getX(0);
                lastEvent[1] = event.getX(1);
                lastEvent[2] = event.getY(0);
                lastEvent[3] = event.getY(1);
                d = rotation(event);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_UP:
                mode = NONE;
                lastEvent = null;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                if (mode == DRAG) {
                    matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                    float dx = event.getX() - start.x;
                    float dy = event.getY() - start.y;
                    matrix.postTranslate(dx, dy);
                } else if (mode == ZOOM) {
                    float newDist = spacing(event);
                    if (newDist > 10f) {
                        matrix.set(savedMatrix);
                        float scale = (newDist / oldDist);
                        matrix.postScale(scale, scale, mid.x, mid.y);
                    }
                    if (lastEvent != null && event.getPointerCount() == 2) {
                        newRot = rotation(event);
                        float r = newRot - d;
                        float[] values = new float[9];
                        matrix.getValues(values);
                        float tx = values[2];
                        float ty = values[5];
                        float sx = values[0];
                        float xc = (view.getWidth() / 2) * sx;
                        float yc = (view.getHeight() / 2) * sx;
                        matrix.postRotate(r, tx + xc, ty + yc);
                    }
                }
                break;
        }

       view.setImageMatrix(matrix);
        return true;
    }


    /**
     * Determine the space between the first two fingers
     */
    private float spacing(MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) - event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) - event.getY(1);
        return FloatMath.sqrt(x * x + y * y);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the mid point of the first two fingers
     */
    private void midPoint(PointF point, MotionEvent event) {
        float x = event.getX(0) + event.getX(1);
        float y = event.getY(0) + event.getY(1);
        point.set(x / 2, y / 2);
    }

    /**
     * Calculate the degree to be rotated by.
     *
     * @param event
     * @return Degrees
     */
    private float rotation(MotionEvent event) {
        double delta_x = (event.getX(0) - event.getX(1));
        double delta_y = (event.getY(0) - event.getY(1));
        double radians = Math.atan2(delta_y, delta_x);
        return (float) Math.toDegrees(radians);
    }
}


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<FrameLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<ImageView android:id="@+id/imageView"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="matrix"
 android:src="@drawable/chill"
 />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:scaleType="matrix" 
    android:src="@drawable/awesome"
   />


</FrameLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

In your xml file set tag for your image with android:tag and at run time get the tag and apply transformation to that particular image.

1.Implement a method in java class,

2.Call that method when either of image is clicked,

3.And identify image by getting its tag using View.getTag(); and apply transformation.

Comment: my problem is I cant touch the first imageview that I added when I add the second ImageView. Any idea how can I access the 1st image?

Comment: Using frame layout i kept one image over other,gave click events to both images and was able to access both images.Let me know where you are facing problems.

Comment: @ JIGAR PANDYA : I'm adding imageviews programmaticaly by clicking a button. the imageview will be added inside the framelayout. When I add the first imageview, the transformations works fine but when I click the button to add a second imageview, the 1st view goes under the 2nd view, so it became untouchable. the only thing that I can touch is the most recent view that I added. Hope you can help :)

Comment: Hey bro!! I just tried the thing that you said and it is working perfectly :)

Comment: @  JIGAR PANDYA : Woah thats great, how did you do it? I'll paste a sample code, kindly check.

Comment: I guess the problem with your code is that most recent image is taking its width and height as FILL_PARENT,so you won't be able to access view below it.For touching 1st image view give some height and width to most recent view programmatically

Comment: :its not actually adding the imageview programmatically. I modify it to add imageview onclick. but it has the same issue. cant touch the 2nd image? any suggestion?

Comment: :yeah, that is the problem. the FILL_PARENT. I tried to set it on WRAP_CONTENT and Im able to access both image but there will be a problem on scaling and rotating the images. You can only rotate and scale the image on its own width and height.

Comment: instead of WRAP_CONTENT give some finite width and height so that you are able to do scaling and rotation and please vote up my answer if you are satisfied with my answers :)

Comment: I did that already and you can only do the transformation on certain portion of the framelayout(the finite width and heigth), w/c what I need to do is place and transform the imageview wherever I want on the framelayout.

Comment: Actually your problem was you were not able to touch image in behind.Now you are asking totally different thing bro

Comment: Yup, that was the question but your suggestion is not a solution. What its doing is just focusing on me enabling to touch the 2nd imgview w/out considering its effects on the general part w/c is the image transformation.